# how to type an array of objects coming from realmDB?

Tags: typescript, react-native, realm

Error: Argument of type 'Results<Courses[] & Object>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Courses[]>'.
Type 'Results<Courses[] & Object>' does not have the following properties of type 'Courses[]': pop, push, reverse, shift, and more 6.ts(2345)

```
// my interface
interface Courses {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  image: string;
}

const [courses, setCourses] = useState<Courses[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function getOfflineCourses() {
      const realmDB = await realm;

      realmDB.write(() => {
        const offlineCourses = realmDB.objects<Courses[]>('Course');
        setCourses(offlineCourses);
      });
    }
    getOfflineCourses();
  }, [realm]);
```

Comment: const offlineCourses: Courses[] = realmDB.objects('Course');

Comment: I tried that way but got no success. error: The 'Results<Object>' type does not have the following properties of the 'Courses[]' type: pop, push, reverse, shift and more 6.ts(2740)

Comment: The question is a bit unclear but if your attempting to read the Course objects from realm, this is the pattern `const courses = realm.objects("Courses");`. That being said, the naming is a little confusing; Realm objects are separate entitites so a course object would be called Course, not Courses. Also the Course object needs to be defined but the object in the question is not the full definition as a Realm object. Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the return I was hoping to add to my state using the following function:

```
setCourses(offlineCourses.toJSON());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also got this issue, my code were typed with generics

```
const [customers, setCustomers] = useState<CustomerProps[]>([]);

async function fetchCustomers() {
setIsLoading(true);
const realm = await getRealm();
try {
  const response = realm
    .objects<CustomerProps[]>("Customer")
    .sorted("created_at")
    .toJSON();

  setCustomers(response);
} ...
```

and i was getting the same error on the hook setCustomer
i've just casted response as 'Props'

```
  setCustomers(response as CustomerProps[]);
```

therefore, the generic cast of `.objects` wasn't needed

**using**

```
├── react-native@0.70.5
├── react@18.1.0
├── realm@11.3.1
└── typescript@4.9.4
```